# web proxy on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, proxy

i am writing a web proxy in java on google App engine.I figured out that the urls can be fected using the url Fetch servce but i have no idea about how to manage cookies and the streams as in youtube .Ne suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) engine, it perfectly allows those features, i think, since it can log in sites.